# How can I import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile

Tags: java, minecraft

I am currently getting into Spigot Pugin developement and need to access GameProfile, because I need it for a plugin (Stuff for changing Skins). I'm using Eclipse.

Now, I've watched a whole ton of tutorials in which GameProfile was used, and all these tutorials just went for

```
import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile;
```

or

```
import net.minecraft.util.SOMETHINGLONG.GameProfile
```

without needing to explain anything why this line is possible.

Here is a guy that had the same problem like me with the second command but apparently could solve it with the first one, so im trying to get this one running. https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/how-to-import-net-minecraft-util.252371/.

If I try to include stuff like this, I see `com.google.common`, `com.oracle` and `com.sun` but com.mojang is nowhere to be seen. I found it has to do something with the .jar files you add to your project, but I don't know how to get com.mojang... into the importable files.

Comment: Try downloading JAR from the here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mojang/minecraft-server/1.4.4

Comment: Error 502, this file is gone...

Comment: Well, as that spigot blog says, everything should have been moved to `net.minecraft`, probably after Microsoft bought out Minecraft from Mojang. So wherever you download the Minecraft server jars from, that's what you should be using. And you're probably referencing an old tutorial

Comment: So this seems to explain the 2 import methods. I actually included the 1.12.2 jar from my ´.minecraft/versions` folder but this ony gives me net.minecraft.servers.*

Comment: And a ton of stuff seems to be missing, including the utils and the GameProfile

Comment: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-plugin-with-maven-using-intellij-idea/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To build up on [SPY_me's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61668448/14769872), here is my solution if you're using Gradle:

```
repositories {
    // ...
    maven {
        name = 'minecraft-repo'
        url = 'https://libraries.minecraft.net/'
        // this lets gradle know where to look for authlib
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.mojang:authlib:1.5.21'
    // this adds the library to the project and the jar when you compile your project
}
```

If you want to download this library directly, here is the jar:

https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/mojang/authlib/1.5.21/authlib-1.5.21.jar

Comment: Just want to add on that you can see what libraries a particular version of Minecraft uses by going to `.minecraft/versions/<version>/<version>.json` (see [here for more information on the .minecraft folder](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/.minecraft)). An array of the libraries used is under the property `libraries`. For example, 1.16.4 uses `com.mojang.authlib.2.1.28`.

Answer (score 4):

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>minecraft-repo</id>
        <url>https://libraries.minecraft.net/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mojang</groupId>
        <artifactId>authlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Why have you added those two things to the Maven pom? The question does not mention Maven, but only Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use IntelliJ, I guess you're using Maven?

If so then paste this in your pom.yml:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!--Spigot API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--Bukkit API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--CraftBukkit API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>craftbukkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```