# How do you import com.mojang.authlib [Maven]

Tags: maven, spigot

I am making a plugin with custom skin textures and I need to use GameProfile which is Mojang authlib. I put it in my pom.xml but it says it cannot find the dependency `Dependency 'com.mojang:authlib:1.5.21' not found` . Here is my full pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>minecraft-repo</id>
            <url>https://libraries.minecraft.net/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>




    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mojang</groupId>
            <artifactId>authlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: It seems to be a typo or a fresh issue because you are alone to get this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467259/how-can-i-import-com-mojang-authlib-gameprofile)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the paperspigot repository it provides mojang authlib from `1.5` to `3.4.40`.

```xml
<repository>
   <id>paper-repo</id>
   <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
</repository>
```

Reference: https://papermc.io/using-the-api