# How to import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I'm currently trying to create a Spigot plugin, but I need to use GameProfile to apply textures, and I can't seem to import it. When I import it using:

```
import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile;
```

I get the error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'mojang'`

I'm using IntelliJ with Maven, and I've been struggling with this issue for two days now. I've tried the solutions suggested in these posts:

[How can I import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467259/how-can-i-import-com-mojang-authlib-gameprofile/61668448#comment109090032_61668448)
https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/how-do-i-access-gameprofile.450589/

None of them have worked so far. In all of these posts, they mention adding a repository and the dependency `authlib-1.5.21`. I've tried each of their solutions, but each time I end up with the same error.

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>minecraft-repo</id>
            <url>https://libraries.minecraft.net/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mojang</groupId>
            <artifactId>authlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

`Dependency 'com.mojang:authlib:1.5.21' not found`

I also tried importing my `spigot-1.20.1.rar` file in `Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies` based on a video I watched, but that didn't work either.

I used the Minecraft extension in IntelliJ to create my plugin, which provides presets. I also tried to do it without using the extension, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the preset of MinecraftDev for IntelliJ use `org.spigotmc:spigot-api` artifact to your dependencies. spigot-api only contains SpigotAPI related code but not any part of the Minecraft or Mojang code. To fix the problem, you should [compile your version of Spigot using their BuildTools](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/)
Compiling with buildtools will add a complete build of spigot (not juste the API) to your maven local repository. This way, you will be able to add `org.spigotmc:spigot` as a maven dependency, and all Minecraft and Mojang imports from the server will be available.

Maven code :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.1-R1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```